# Assign value number in char of alphabet in Python

Tags: python

I want assign a number in my char alphabet such as

> a : 1 b :2 c:3 ...z=26

I have already created the alphabet and numeric values,but doing the test with the print, the result is a list with first all the characters of the alphabet and then the numeric values
I have already looked if there were other solutions, but they use functions that are still obscure to me that I am beginner.
So I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use built-in constructs if it's possible because I want to better understand the logic

My code:

```
#create alphabet

list_alphabet = [] 
alpha = 'a' #first letter in alphabet
for i in range(0,26):
  list_alphabet.append(alpha)
  alpha = chr(ord(alpha)+1)

#Assign number value 

number = 1 
for j in range(1,26):
  list_alphabet.append(number)
  number = number + 1


#print(list_alphabet)
```

Comment: Would `{letter: i+1 for i, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}` suffice?

Comment: I see that there is string.ascii_lowercase for create alphabet but I never seen enumerate

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use build in functions you can try this:

```
#create alphabet

list_alphabet = []
alpha = 'a' #first letter in alphabet
for i in range(0,26):
  list_alphabet.append(alpha)
  alpha = chr(ord(alpha)+1)

#Assign number value

new_list = []
for j in range(1,27):
    new_list.append((list_alphabet[j-1], j))

print(new_list)
```

If you want to use `zip` function you can try:

```
#create alphabet
list_alphabet = []
alpha = 'a' #first letter in alphabet
for i in range(0,26):
  list_alphabet.append(alpha)
  alpha = chr(ord(alpha)+1)


list_alphabet = list(zip(list_alphabet, range(1,27)))
print(list_alphabet)
```

Both outputs:

```
Out: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7), ('h', 8), ('i', 9), ('j', 10), ('k', 11), ('l', 12), ('m', 13), ('n', 14), ('o', 15), ('p', 16), ('q', 17), ('r', 18), ('s', 19), ('t', 20), ('u', 21), ('v', 22), ('w', 23), ('x', 24), ('y', 25), ('z', 26)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp):

```
result_dict = {}
alpha = 'a' #first letter in alphabet
for i in range(0,26):
  result_dict[alpha] = i + 1
  alpha = chr(ord(alpha)+1)

result_dict

{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 4,
 'e': 5,
 'f': 6,
 'g': 7,
 'h': 8,
 'i': 9,
 'j': 10,
 'k': 11,
 'l': 12,
 'm': 13,
 'n': 14,
 'o': 15,
 'p': 16,
 'q': 17,
 'r': 18,
 's': 19,
 't': 20,
 'u': 21,
 'v': 22,
 'w': 23,
 'x': 24,
 'y': 25,
 'z': 26}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
dict_list ={}
for a in range(97,123):
    dict_list[chr(a)]=a-96
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to create a dictionary

```
import string
{letter: i+1 for i, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}
```

or the following to create a list of tuples

```
import string
[letter, i+1 for i, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)]
```

both use the `ascii_lowercase` which contains the lowercase alphabet, then enumerate will give you an index along with the element you're iterating over, then using a dictionary/list comprehension to get the desired output